# How to properly use xmlfile api from lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I have a large (5+ gigs) XML file which I need to parse, do some operation & write a new XML file.

dummy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" catalog-id="test-catalog">
    <header>
        <name>Product Catalog</name>
    </header>

    <product product-id="1234">
        <available-flag>false</available-flag>
        <name>product1</name>
    </product>
    <product product-id="5678">
        <available-flag>false</available-flag>
        <name>product1</name>
    </product>
    <product product-id="9999">
        <available-flag>false</available-flag>
        <name>product1</name>
    </product>    
</catalog>
```

As you see the above XML has 3 `product` tags & I need to filter some product-ids on basis of a pre-defined list of ids.

I am using lxml `iterparse` to parse the XML iteratively & want to use `xmlfile` API to create a new XML incrementally to keep the memory footprint low. So, my motive is to filter out the product tags which don't meet the criteria & copy the rest of the XML tags as it is.

```
from lxml import etree
f = './dummy.xml'

f1 = './test.xml'
context = etree.iterparse(f, events=('start',))
productsToExport = ['1234']


with etree.xmlfile(f1, encoding='utf-8') as xf:
    xf.write_declaration()
    with xf.element('catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" catalog-id="test-catalog"'):
        for event, element in context:
            tagName = etree.QName(element.tag).localname
            if (tagName == 'product'):
                pid = element.get('product-id')
                if (pid in productsToExport):
                    xf.write(element)
            elif (tagName == 'header'):
                xf.write(element) # copy existing header tag as it is
```

Above code works ok & generates a XML as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" catalog-id="test-catalog">
    <header xmlns="http://www.namespace.com">
        <name>Product Catalog</name>
    </header>

    <product xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" product-id="1234">
        <available-flag>false</available-flag>
        <name>product1</name>
    </product>
</catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" catalog-id="test-catalog">
```

If you observe the above XML it has few issues:

- Closing `<catalog>` tag has `xmlns` & `catalog-id` present in it
- All tags like `header, product` have `xmlns` attribute present in it

I checked [xmlfile api documentation](https://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation) but couldn't find a way to fix above issues.

**EDIT:**

I managed to resolve the 1st issue by using below

```
attribs = {'xmlns' : 'http://www.namespace.com', 'catalog-id' : 'test-catalog'}
 with xf.element('catalog', attribs):
     # previous logic
```

So, now am left with removing the namespace from every element.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply rebuilding the XML tree with `lxml.etree` methods instead of the `xmlfile` API, still in the context of your `iterparse`:

```
from lxml import etree

f = './dummy.xml'
f1 = './test.xml'    
productsToExport = ['1234']

# ROOT ELEMENT WITH DEFUALT NAMESPACE
my_nmsp = {None: 'http://www.namespace.com'}

# INITIALIZE ITERATOR
context = etree.iterparse(f, events=('start',))

for event, element in context:    
    tagName = etree.QName(element.tag).localname   

    for prod in productsToExport:
        root = etree.Element('catalog', nsmap=my_nmsp)
        root.text = '\n\t'
        root.attrib['catalog-id'] = "test-catalog"

        # PRODUCT ELEMENT
        if tagName == 'product':
            pid = element.get('product-id')

            if pid == prod:
                root.append(element)

        # HEADER ELEMENT        
        elif (tagName == 'header'):
            root.append(element)

        # OUTPUT TREE TO FILE
        with open(f1, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

**Output**

```
<catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com" catalog-id="test-catalog">
    <header>
        <name>Product Catalog</name>
    </header>

    <product product-id="1234">
        <available-flag>false</available-flag>
        <name>product1</name>
    </product> 
</catalog>
```

Comment: Thanks but this will keep the complete XML tree in memory & will not write xml to file incrementally

Comment: If you want one product element per output. You can simply nest this process including *root* assignment and `to_string` inside a higher `for` loop of *productsToExport* list. Be sure to adjust `if pid in productsToExport:` to `if pid = [iterator variable]:`

Comment: @Parfait: Your code doesn't look correct. If `productsToExport` has multiple pids I don't think output will be correct. Also, with multiple pids you will parse the XML file twice `etree.iterparse(f, events=('start',))`

Comment: @RanRag ... This solution iterates through *productsToExport* so expects multiple pids. Also, I have switched the iteration to not traverse the XML multiple times.